# Efficiently create a wide table in Pandas from multiple rows via a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 600 column dataframe that is approximately 1,000,000 rows. All cells are float32.

I need to move a rolling window (length 30) through the dataframe row-wise to create a new row which combines those in the window. This would will be `600 * 30 == 18000` in width with approximately `1,000,000 - 30` in length (rows). Because of the rolling window, rows from the original dataframe are duplicated (by design) in the result.

Below is some rough (*untested*) code to summarize the requirements. Actually I would allocate a numpy array of the correct length instead of the `Xy_hist = []` python list.

```
# tmp is the large df already defined
total_size = tmp.shape[0]
window_size = 30
Xy_hist = []
for x in range(total_size-window_size):
    tmp_df = tmp.iloc[0+x:window_size+x,:].stack().to_frame().T
    tmp_df.columns = tmp_df.columns.get_level_values(1)
    Xy_hist.append(tmp_df)
res = pd.concat(Xy_hist)
```

I believe this approach to be very memory inefficient and presumably computationally inefficient too. Is there a better more pythonic and/or Pandas native approach to solve this problem?

Comment: why are you doing `stack`? could you provide few rows of `tmp` as example ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you need, just my bulls eye solution, you can do:

```
total_size = tmp.shape[0]
window_size = 30
res = pd.concat([tmp.iloc[x:window_size+x,:] for x in range(0, total_size, window_size)])
```